# Compare two tables on different servers in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to compare two tables, one on UAT server and and one on live.

I used to use a similar query to the below.

Can someone help? I want to just display any differences, using a EXCEPT.

```
:CONNECT servername
PRINT 'live'

SELECT * 
FROM [database].[tablename] AS pm

go

:CONNECT servername
PRINT 'uat'

SELECT * 
FROM [database].[tablename] AS pm

go
```

Comment: If you haven't already, add one of the servers as a linked server on the other. Then you'd just make a query using the linked server. e.g. `select x, y, z from [myTable] except select x, y, z from [myLinkedServer].[myLinkedServerDatabase].[myLinkedServerSchema].[myTable]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see openquery here
[OPENQUERY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms188427.aspx)

and use it like this

```
 --link other server
 EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='10.223.224.21\servername' 
 EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin '10.223.224.21\servername', 'false', NULL, 
 'sa','password'

-- Fetch data from the other database server
SELECT *
INTO #myTempTable
FROM OPENQUERY([DB2], 'SELECT * FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB2].[dbo].[MyOtherTable]')

-- Now I can join my temp table to see the data
SELECT * FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB1].[dbo].[MyTable] tab1
INNER JOIN #myTempTable tab2 ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

Comment: Hi Johnine, Thanks for your input. I have tried this query. What I I put in the DB2 part 'FROM OPENQUERY([DB2]',? the Server name? I tried both the database and server name. Getting error.  'Could not find server in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.

Comment: Hello , you need to link other server using this command :
`EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='10.223.224.21\servername'
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin '10.223.224.21\servername', 'false', NULL, 'sa', 'password'
`

Comment: then to check if the server was linked .execute the command
`sp_helpserver`

Comment: Then you can now compare two tables
`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([10.223.224.21\servername], 'SELECT * FROM [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Tablename]')`

Comment: Thank you. Worked adding linked server