# SQL how to compare two tables from different servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table job_order with column order_no in my store_db. Is there a way or query that I can compare if data from the order_no column matched with the same column but on a different database server?

Note that server1 and server2 has the same database. I would appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two tables on different servers in SQL Server 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606846/compare-two-tables-on-different-servers-in-sql-server-2014)

Answer (score 0):

Different approaches can be used to achieve the table comparison:

1. Create a Linked Server connection, then create a Stored Procedure that performs a comparison on the Target Server.

A wide option exists to achieve an effective table data comparison.

References:

[Table Comparison](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2779/ways-to-compare-and-find-differences-for-sql-server-tables-and-data/)